# Devolver parámetros correctos de views.py a javascript - Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con el framework `Django` y quiero que al pulsar un botón se me ejecute una función `python` situada en `view.py`.

He conseguido (con `js`) que al pulsar el botón se me ejecute y pasarle parámetros, ya que me función tiene un `print` y me los muestra. Pero no consigo devolver el resultado de nuevo al `js` para que aparezca en mi web. No me sale ningún error ni por la consola de visual studio ni por la consola del navegador. ¿A que se debe mi error?

Código JS:

```
$('#prueba').click(function() {
    alert('boton pulsado');
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    alert(csrftoken)
    a =1;
    b =3;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/../../prueba/',
        type: 'POST',
        headers:{"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
        data: {
            'a': a,
            'b': b, 
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.Result);
            alert(response.Result);
        }
    });
    alert('fin') 
});
```

Código de la función situada en views.py:

```
def vista_sumar(request):
    ctx = 'none'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        c = int(a) + int(b)
        ctx = {'Result':c}

        print('sss',ctx)

    return render(request,'main.html',ctx)
```

Lo dicho, consigo llegar a la función porque esta me imprime el resultado de la suma, pero luego el `return`nunca llega...

Del `js` me funcionan todos los `alert` excepto el del `success`, así que entiendo que le estoy devolviendo mal el resultado y se produce un error y en consecuencia el `log` nunca se ejecuta.

PD: Viendo otros posts, pienso que quizás deba pasar el resultado cómo `POST` pero no he conseguido hacerlo empleando el `render`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que la respuesta llegue al lado del cliente (JS), debes devolver un `JsonResponse`, no un `HttpResponse` (que es lo que devuelve `render` por defecto)

Si pruebas esto verás que funciona:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def vista_sumar(request):
    ctx = 'none'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST['a']
        b = request.POST['b']
        c = int(a) + int(b)

    return JsonResponse({'Result': c})
```

Comment: Una pregunta, y si quiero ahora emplearla en mi `js` como la guardo? porque he hecho `var prueba = response.Result;` dentro del success, y sustituido el `alert('Fin')` por `alert(prueba)` y falla porque intenta ejecutarlo antes y claro, no está definida. Es decir, yo hago todo esto para tener nuevas variables a usar.

Comment: prueba a hacer `response.data.Result` en vez de `response.Result`

Comment: Me da un typeError de tipo undefined. Claro porque la gracia de todo esto es haber generado unos datos con my script de python y ahora poder verlos y trabajarlos tanto en mis templates cómo en js. Si sabes cómo ayudarme te lo agradecería bastante ya que llevo días parado por esto y  si no igualmente muchas gracias

Comment: Por qué no tratas de imprimir qué contiene `response` en el `success` para así poder ver como llegar hasta la variable `Result`?